# Storing chart data in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, charts

I have a web app (Rails) that I want to use to create chart. For now what I do is :

- Upload the file containing my data to display
- Store this file and associate it to a model Sample
- When I want to view this Sample I extract the data from the file previously uploaded and create the chart using ChartJS

But I don't really like this solution because the charts are recreated every time, and most of all I want to be able to **do some statistics** over the time on my charts data and if I keep them into file, it's difficult...

Each sample is about ~1000 rows, so it seems "not conventional" to store 1000 new rows every time I create a sample ?

---

Today I have :

```
Sample
..... id : int
..... attachment : txt file containing the data
```

Is it OK to change it to :

```
Sample
..... id : int
..... attachment : txt file containing the data
..... chart_data_id : associated ChartData

ChartData
..... id : int
..... x : int
..... y : int
```

I hope I'm clear with my explanations... For example, in my database I would have one Sample whiwh has_many ChartData :

```
Sample(id: 1, attachment: my_file, chart_id: 10)

ChartData(id: 10, x: 0, y: 1)
ChartData(id: 10, x: 3, y: 2)
ChartData(id: 10, x: 5, y: 7)
.....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, having a `ChartData` object is, as you already have guessed, a perfectly good way to go about it. Although, if `Sample` `has_many :chart_data`, the foreign key needs to be `sample_id` in the `ChartData` table so that `ChartData` can have unique IDs.

And even if this is not a model structure that is used that often, any halfway decent database will have no problem storing a few million rows (in SQLite the maximum is 2^64). You'd really need a *lot* of samples for this to become problematic and even then there are mechanisms to make it work (i.e. partitioning etc).

There are however other possibilites, too. If for example you use PostgreSQL and as long as the only attributes of `ChartData` are `x` and `y`, you could consider using an array of [Point](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-geometric.html) for the attribute containing the data.

Something like

```
create_table :samples do |t|
  t.point :chart_data, array: true, default: []
end
```

Points are the only geometry type supported by Rails out of the box and [will be treated as arrays](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#geometric-types) upon retrieval from the database.

Or you could even use the [JSON type](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json) to store a Hash or Array in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the tips I will take a look at all this solutions to know which one is the better for me :)